# Is there any other way to call the function except setTimeOut()?

Tags: angular, typescript, svg

```
if(i==1){
        this.resetScreens();
        this.editJobScreen1 = true;
    if(this.selectedLocations.length > 0){
        this.locationService.getLocationByInput({
          maxResultCount:16,
          skipCount: 0
        }).subscribe((ele)=>{
          this.Regions = ele.items;
          this.Regions.forEach((element) => {
          this.HiringRegionMapComponent.list.push(element.id);
        });
        })
        for(let i=0;i<this.selectedLocations.length;i++){
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.HiringRegionMapComponent?.addColor(this.selectedLocations[i].id);
          }, 150);
        }

      }
    }
```

## Problem

I have an SVG map which I'm filling on the bases of their ID's. This condition is called inside a function when user presses the back button. Without setTimeOut(), the function addColor() is not giving the output (i.e. it need some delay to work IDK why :) ). With setTimeout(), most of the time its working but its also breaking about 2 out of 20 times. I need an valid solution that might help not to break it.

## Expectation

Technologies:

1. angular (11.0.0)
2. dotnetcore(5.0)

An obvious solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because you are running out of Angular's context.

SetTimeout, like other methods, is monkey-patched to detect changes at the end of the execution of its code. But it's better to use NgZone for that, or even better, trigger the change detection yourself, or EVEN better, try to not quit angular's context.

```js
// NgZone

constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

// ...

this.zone.run(() => {
  if (i == 1) 
  // ...
});

// Change detector

constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

// ...

for(let i=0;i<this.selectedLocations.length;i++) {
  // ...
}
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your solution fails when your service is slower than the timeout.
Just put the for loop inside the subscribe function.